# Cactus id (Polaskia?)

Tags: identification, cactus

I have a cactus here (9 cm tall), and I think it is *Polaskia chichipe*, however it might be *P. chende* as well. I don't know how to tell difference. It might as well not be *Polaskia* at all. Can someone tell the difference and help me ID this one? Thanks in advance.

[image]